# Sybase ASE 15.0.2 - dynamically update statistics/ index statistics

Tags: performance, sap-ase

I am trying to update statistics to some of our tables whose names I receive as input to my procedure. But, I couldn't compile the procedure with the below code.

```
update index statistics @tableName
```

Aren't dynamic table names allowed? Or, would the below statement work?

```
select @statsCmd = 'update index statistics '+@tableName
exec(@statsCmd)
```

Also, what are the notable differences between "update statistics" and "update index statistics"?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that `update statistics` does not allow dynamic table names, but the second statement should work without issue.

Regarding `update statistics` & `update index statistics`:

[Update statistics](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/CIHFHDEF.htm) can be run against tables without indexes, and other non-index objects, as well as against indexes.  If run against an index, it actually executes an `update index statistics` behind the scenes.  [Update index statistics](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/CIHGFHFG.htm) only updates statistics for the indices on the specified table.

Also, have you looked into using the [Job Scheduler, and the `datachange`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1570/html/queryprocessing/CIHDHBIA.htm) function to automate your update statistics?